# Prerogative of future world

Tags: society, humans, earth-like

It is a thousand years in the future. Humans brains are obsolete for thinking and are used only as a central control center for organ commands and heuristic processing (reactionary or first impulse thoughts easily programmed). Every human born, after twenty years, is surgically implanted with a piece of wire that wraps around their vagus nerve and/or a tooth that connects to the audio nerve in their jaw is drilled out and filled with a ceramic antenna.

The entire planet is covered by towers which emit high frequency ultrasound messages unable to be recognized by the conscious mind. These messages are all set at nano frequencies which follow a path of instructions which fulfill a predestined life cycle. And of course there are a billion different set of instructions. So each human lives a life unaware that they are being controlled remotely by the towers.

And since this is a thousand years in the future, the towers are maintained by soulless robots who create more of themselves in a factory. And all the messages are predetermined so far in advance they are only ultrasound instructions .

These instructions are, by the frequency, directed toward an organic radio inside the limbic system of the brain that turns the messages into desirable and accepted ideas by stimulating certain receptors or releasing brain chemicals.  So now the world is full of these organic robots. And what is horrific is that these human robots have only one desire left, to be gods, so they start reprogramming  the other animals until the world comes to a stand still.

My question is, what would be the purpose of their lives if they no longer have free will? Is it just to reproduce and make more human robots? Or is that actually cruel?

Do they become fulfilled by pretending they are gods? Or is that an indication, perhaps to another god, of their lack of a soul. Or just what are some ideas about the purpose of such planet in a galaxy of other civilizations?

To summarize I am wondering where society is heading when all it does is create smaller boxes for us to fit inside? If all the unintended behaviors of humans were eradicated to a point of defining all actions, is this not a creation of slavery?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85854/discussion-on-question-by-robus-prerogative-of-future-world).

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that the question ( as currently worded) seems vague, I am reminded of several other stories that involve protagonist revision, often in the form of a disruptive change, or an outright revolution.
  In Rand's "Anthem" the protagonist is somehow born "different", and knows innately that he is somehow representative of a better life, one with individual identity.
  I would recommend that you consider the old saying " The only true evidence of life is growth".  With forward thinking, cultural development, even evolution drawn to a halt, your proposed world-line is possibly doomed, unless the pursuit of change sufficient to promote survival is brought into the world.
  Good Luck with your story!

Comment: I appreciate this insight as your answer gives context to my question. survival here seems already guaranteed, but is survival the goal of a higher intelligence? Or is it something else?